# EaselJS: BitmapSequence issue in a OOP-like class

Tags: javascript, html, canvas

I have been playing a bit with gskinner.com's EaselJS library (http://easeljs.com/, http://easeljs.com/examples/game/game.html), which makes dealing with HTML5's canvas a lot easier.

So I'm trying to remake something like Space Invaders in the canvas. So far it's not much, just the payer moving left to right. See the progress here: http://jansensan.net/experiments/easeljs-space-invader/

For the invaders, I needed an animation, so I followed a tutorial on how to do so: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=HaJ615V6qLk

Now that is all good and dandy, however I follow gskinner.com's way of creating "classes": http://easeljs.com/examples/game/Ship.js I'm not certain if I can call that a class, but it is used as such.

So below is the class that I wrote for the Invader, however it seems like the BitmapSequence does not seem to be added to EaselJS's stage. Anyone can guide me through this? Thanks!

```
// REFERENCES
/*
http://easeljs.com/examples/game/Ship.js
*/


// CLASS
(function(window)
{
    function Invader()
    {
        this.initialize();
    }


    var p = Invader.prototype = new Container();


    // CONSTANTS


    // VARS
    p.image;
    p.bitmapSequence;


    // CONSTRUCTOR
    p.Container_initialize = p.initialize;  //unique to avoid overiding base class


    p.initialize = function()
    {
        this.Container_initialize();

        this.image = new Image();
        this.image.onload = p.imageLoadHandler;
        this.image.onerror = p.imageErrorHandler;
        this.image.src = "assets/images/invader-spritesheet.png";
    }


    p.imageLoadHandler = function()
    {
        var frameData = {
            anim:[0, 1, "anim"]
        }

        var spriteSheet = new SpriteSheet(p.image, 22, 16, frameData);

        p.bitmapSequence = new BitmapSequence(spriteSheet);
        p.bitmapSequence.regX = p.bitmapSequence.spriteSheet.frameWidth * 0.5;
        p.bitmapSequence.regY = p.bitmapSequence.spriteSheet.frameHeight * 0.5;
        p.bitmapSequence.gotoAndStop("anim");

        p.addChild(p.bitmapSequence);
    }


    p.imageErrorHandler = function()
    {
        console.log("Error: the url assets/images/invader-spritesheet.png could not be loaded.");
    }


    window.Invader = Invader;
}(window));
```

Answer (score 1):

Does you `p.image/this.Container_initalize` actually exist at that point? As you switch between using `this.` and `p.` between your init and other functions, while they might seem to be the same practice has often taught me its not the case. Try changing your init function to this:

```
p.initialize = function()
{
    p.Container_initialize();

    p.image = new Image();
    p.image.onload = p.imageLoadHandler;
    p.image.onerror = p.imageErrorHandler;
    p.image.src = "assets/images/invader-spritesheet.png";
}
```